# Disable a:focus and a:active color?

Tags: html, css

I have a base CSS that defines this:

```
a:hover, a:focus {
    color: black;
}
```

I want to have a specific link that overrides and does not trigger focus, but still triggers hover.

How can i do something like this to override the color setting?

```
a:focus{
    color: none;
}
```

I've tried color:transparent to no avail, focus still triggers.

Comment: If it is a specific link use a class selector and apply the color you want for .yourselector:hover and .yourselector:focus.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. But the selector needs to be different, otherwise it will just override the previous `a:focus` selector. And the overriding selector would have to be more specific (adding a class, for example). Some code would be nice. Maybe a jsFiddle?

Comment: I am already using a specific class, but because the base css is applied using the a selector, it will affect my class as well

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```css
a:hover{
color:green;
}
.class:hover, .class:focus {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="class">dsadsfdsfsd</a>
<a href="#">dsadsfdsfsd</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need like this. This will inherit the color from parent.

```
    a:focus {
    color: inherit !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please apply this css.

```
a:hover { text-decoration: none !important; color :none; border: 0px; -moz-outline-style: none;} 
a:focus { text-decoration: none !impoartant; outline: none;-moz-outline-style: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use initial to set element style to default.

a:focus {
    color: initial !important;
    }